# Linking a new viewcontroller to Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, ios5

There is probably a simple solution but I can't figure it out.

I am using storyboards for the interface.

I start with a tab bar controller, but before the user is allowed to use the app the user has to authenticate himself trough a loginview which is modally pushed at the start.

I want to configure the loginview at the same storyboard, but I can't seam to figure out how to link the view controller at the storyboard and my code.

**What I have done:**

- Create a new UIViewController subclass trough file > new > new file.
- Drag a new UIViewController in the story board
- Set the class in the custom class tab
- drags a UILabel for test purpose.
- run

No label...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Pull on a new UIViewController that will act as the login view controller onto the MainStoryboard. In the attribute inspector change the identifier to LoginViewController (or something appropriate). Then add

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

to the First view controller and the login screen will be loaded from your storyboard and presented.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I have .m and .h files and I want no .xib file but configure the view in the main storyboard.

Comment: I have explained how to create the Login Screen inside the Main Storyboard so you don't need a xib.

Comment: But that's not what I want. For example when you have a dynamic table-view you want to push an view when a cell is pressed. But how can you make that with storyboards.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Here is the project that I created if you want to have a quick look and let me know if it helps or if you can clarify where I am going wrong with your question we should be able to find a solution. http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?attachment_id=512

Comment: Thats almost what I want. The only addition I need is the code behind for that login view. So that I can manage the login. (thanks for helping me out)

Comment: If you just want the first view controller in that storyboard (ie, the initial one) you can use `instantiateInitialViewController` instead of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: but, if the login successful, how can i go back to the tab bar menu? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Scott Sherwood above is most correct answer I found after lot of searching. Though very slight change as per new SDK (6.1), presentModalViewController shows deprecated.

Here is very small change to above answer.

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    HomeViewController * hvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    [hvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:hvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm  new in this field. But if the first view controller is a navigation view controller and its rootviewcontroller is  a table view controller.  If you want to push a view controller like the LoginViewController when you click the cell, and you also want to go back to the table view by using the navigation bar. I recommend this way:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

   UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController *controller = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller   animated:YES];
}
```

In this way, you can  have the navigation.

By the way, I don't know why this kind of problem you asked will appear. I guess when the loginviewcontroller is created in the code, its view is not the view in the storyboard. If someone know the cause, please tell me! thanks!