# Prompt another UIViewcontroller at storyboard at the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

I'm using storyboard as the interface and start with a tab bar controller.
let's say i have tab1, tab2, accountsetting.

before the user is allowed to use the app, the user have to authenticate first. I called it pin. I already follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978932/linking-a-new-viewcontroller-to-storyboard), and i can prompt the pin UI. But i got a problem. 
I don't how to disappear this pin UI if my validation is true. I do validation by using `sqlite`.

To move to the pin UI, I use this code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
FirstTimeViewController *firstViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PinViewController"];
[firstViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

here is the picture:

[image]

Actually i can just create and make the UI pin become the initial, but user can disable the UI pin at the application pin.

whenever i click on the action button, if the validation success i will jump to the main menu. How can i go back to my tab bar if my validation success? Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT**
here is my application pin menu.

[image]

Can i use the same class? because to enable/disable i already create a class to handle it. use the same class i mean is for UI PIN. so i dont need to waste to create a new file. If i using a same class, how can i send an object to that class through below code? because i try and still got an error. thanks.

```
    [firstViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things that will hopefully help you along.

Firstly `presentModalViewController` is deprecated, and where possible you should try to use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

As far as I understand from your question you're displaying your PIN entry screen modally. If that's the case, all you need to do to get rid of it and return to the screen you called it from is call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` once you've determined the PIN is correct.

It may be this isn't what you're asking and I've misunderstood your question, in which case just let me know!

**Edit:** OK - I think I get your problem now. You're displaying your PIN view in `viewDidAppear`, but you never actually test to see if the user has already entered a correct PIN (i.e, are logged in). This means every time the user goes to that view  they'll immediately see the PIN view.

You will need to add a conditional test that checks whether the user is logged in (has entered a valid PIN during that session) - if not, you can modally display the PIN view, otherwise just carry on as normal.

Comment: hi @lxt, thanks for your answer. yaa, that is what i want. I already follow your instruction and try it. i can go to the UI PIN, and validate. but after validate, jump back to the tab bar menu. but suddenly jump again to the UI PIN. how to handle this? I already update my code. thanks.

Comment: "You will need to add a conditional test that checks whether the user is logged in" -> using sqlite? do you got any sample for this? thanks. if i'm using sqlite, maybe i can add a field called session. if login success change to 1. default is 0. but how can i handle the sqlite if the user kill the apps? i mean quit the apps. btw check my edit also. thanks.