# Linking Storyboard with non-storyboard project

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have one iOS project with no storyboard or xib file at all,

so now the client would like to create one function that can show news feed in table view.

I may develop the function using previous method, without xib or storyboard, however I would like to use either Interface builder or storyboard since it is way easier.

My question is, 
can I do this?

and if I can, may someone teach me step by step how to link the storyboard or IB with my project?

Thank You.

Comment: either change entire structure of app or just stay with old one.

Comment: For learn new ways (story board) you can make shample apps . you can follow these tutorials  http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, it's still there. Here are the steps to assign a custom view controller class to your view controller:

1. Choose your view controller in the list of scenes on the left side.

[image: Choose view controller screenshot]

2. Choose the Identify Inspector on the right side.
3. Choose the custom view controller class from the Class list.

[image: Choose custom view controller class screenshot]

[for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978932/linking-a-new-viewcontroller-to-storyboard?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Just create storyboard files as much as you want and instantiate from storyboards.

[image]

If you have a TapRecommend.storyboard as above image, you can instantiate any UIViewController from it with the code below.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard    = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TabRecommend" bundle:nil];
ProductDetailVC *dv         = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductDetailVC"];
```

`ProductDetailVC` must be designed in the storyboard, and named the exact ID.

[image]

[image]